# Powershell Excel Graph PlotBy Column Instead of Row

Tags: excel, powershell

Thank you all in advanced.

I am trying to create a Script that will gather information from a customer environment and will then create Excel Workbooks and Sheets for each component. what i am stuck in at the moment is the graph in the excel.

This graph will draw the graph of the CPU and Memory Utilization for the NSX Manager (Which is a linux machine at the end) from the data populated into the excel sheet already. so the script will add the info of the CPU and Memory utilization over time on the Excel sheet and then draw the graph from the data added.

Tha issue is that the graph plot is based on the row and i want it to change into column.

So the output of the script at the moment give me the following:
[Wrong Ploting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft89n.png)

And it should be as follow: [Correct Ploting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01rTd.png)

PS: the Correct one was done by a normal Powershell graphing.

I know that thier is a method called Chart.PlotBy = xlColumns however i can not find the exact sintax to write it as all the available example over google is for VBA.

Code is as follow:

```
#Create the title of 12th section in the Work Book Sheet for the NSX Manager Resource Usage Historic Info.
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(70,4)= 'NSX Manager Resource Usage Historic Info'
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(70,4).Font.Size = 14 
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(70,4).Font.Bold=$True 
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(70,4).Font.Name = "Calibri"  
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(70,4).Font.ColorIndex = 2
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(70,4).Interior.ColorIndex = 9
$Range = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range("D70","F70")
$Range.Merge() | Out-Null
$Range.HorizontalAlignment = -4108
$Range.verticalalignment = -4108
$Range.BorderAround(1,2,48)

#Create Categories of this Sections.
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,4)= "Time Stamp"
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,4).Font.Size = 12 
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,4).Font.Bold=$True 
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,4).Font.Name = "Calibri"  
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,4).Font.ColorIndex = 2
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,4).Interior.ColorIndex = 16
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,5)= "CPU"
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,5).Font.Size = 12 
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,5).Font.Bold=$True 
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,5).Font.Name = "Calibri"  
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,5).Font.ColorIndex = 2
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,5).Interior.ColorIndex = 16
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,6)= "Memory"
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,6).Font.Size = 12 
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,6).Font.Bold=$True 
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,6).Font.Name = "Calibri"  
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,6).Font.ColorIndex = 2
$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item(71,6).Interior.ColorIndex = 16
$Range = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range("D71")
$Range.HorizontalAlignment = -4108
$Range.verticalalignment = -4108
$Range.BorderAround(1,2,48)
$Range = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range("E71")
$Range.HorizontalAlignment = -4108
$Range.verticalalignment = -4108
$Range.BorderAround(1,2,48)
$Range = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range("F71")
$Range.HorizontalAlignment = -4108
$Range.verticalalignment = -4108
$Range.BorderAround(1,2,48)


#Create the Content Values of 12th section in the Work Book Sheet for the NSX Manager Resource Usage Historic Info.
$ReqRow = 72
Foreach ($Line in $NsxCpuHistoricUsage) {
    $Output = $Line.Timestamp
    $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item($ReqRow,4)= "$Output"
    $Output = $Line.Value
    $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item($ReqRow,5)= "$Output"
    $OutPut = ($NsxMemoryHistoricUsage | Where-Object {$_.Timestamp -Match $Line.Timestamp}).Value
    $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Cells.Item($ReqRow,6)= "$Output"
    $ReqRow++
}

$start1 = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.range("D72")
$EndOfCell1 = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range($start1,$start1.End($xlDirection::xlDown))
$Range = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range("D72:D$($EndOfCell1.item($EndOfCell1.count).Row)")
$Range.Font.Size = 12 
$Range.Font.Bold=$True
$Range.HorizontalAlignment = -4108
$Range.verticalalignment = -4108
$Range.BorderAround(1,2,1)
$start2 = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.range("E72")
$EndOfCell2 = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range($start2,$start2.End($xlDirection::xlDown))
$Range = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range("E72:E$($EndOfCell2.item($EndOfCell2.count).Row)")
$Range.Font.Size = 12 
$Range.Font.Bold=$False
$Range.HorizontalAlignment = -4108
$Range.verticalalignment = -4108
$Range.BorderAround(1,2,1)
$start3 = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.range("F72")
$EndOfCell3 = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range($start3,$start3.End($xlDirection::xlDown))
$Range = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range("F72:F$($EndOfCell3.item($EndOfCell3.count).Row)")
$Range.Font.Size = 12 
$Range.Font.Bold=$False
$Range.HorizontalAlignment = -4108
$Range.verticalalignment = -4108
$Range.BorderAround(1,2,1)


#----------------------------------------------------


#Create Chart for NSX Manager Resource Historic Utilization
$NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Shapes.AddChart().Chart
$NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.ChartType = $xlChart::xlLine
$NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.HasTitle = $True
$NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.HasLegend = $True
$NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.ChartTitle.Text = "NSX Manager Resource Historic Utilization"
$xaxis = $NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.Axes($xlAxes::XlCategory)  
$xaxis.HasTitle  = $True
$xaxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Time"
$yaxis = $NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.Axes($xlAxes::XlValue)
$yaxis.HasTitle  = $True
$yaxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Utilization Percentage (%)"
$start1 = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.range("D71")
$Y1 = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range($start1,$start1.End($xlDirection::xlDown))
$start1 = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.range("F71")
$X1 = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range($start1,$start1.End($xlDirection::xlDown))
$chartdata1=$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range("D$($Y1.item(1).Row):D$($Y1.item($Y1.count).Row),F$($X1.item(1).Row):F$($X1.item($X1.count).Row)")
$NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.SetSourceData($chartdata1)
$RangeToCover = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range("D47:F67")
$ChartObj = $NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.Parent
$ChartObj.Top = $RangeToCover.Top
$ChartObj.Left = $RangeToCover.Left
$ChartObj.Height = $RangeToCover.Height
$ChartObj.Width = $RangeToCover.Width


#----------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be much apritiated

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get it working by adding the below:

$xlPlotBy = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRowCol]

$NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.PlotBy = $xlPlotBy::xlColumns

```
    $NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Shapes.AddChart().Chart
    $NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.ChartType = $xlChart::xlLine
    $NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.PlotBy = $xlPlotBy::xlColumns
    $NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.HasTitle = $True
    $NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.HasLegend = $True
    $NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.ChartTitle.Text = "NSX Manager Resource Historic Utilization"
    $xaxis = $NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.Axes($xlAxes::XlCategory)  
    $xaxis.HasTitle  = $True
    $xaxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Time"
    $yaxis = $NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.Axes($xlAxes::XlValue)
    $yaxis.HasTitle  = $True
    $yaxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Utilization Percentage (%)"
    $start1 = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.range("D71")
    $Y1 = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range($start1,$start1.End($xlDirection::xlDown))
    $start1 = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.range("F71")
    $X1 = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range($start1,$start1.End($xlDirection::xlDown))
    $chartdata1=$NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range("D$($Y1.item(1).Row):D$($Y1.item($Y1.count).Row),F$($X1.item(1).Row):F$($X1.item($X1.count).Row)")
    $NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.SetSourceData($chartdata1)
    $RangeToCover = $NsxManagerWorkSheet.Range("D47:F67")
    $ChartObj = $NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.Parent
    $ChartObj.Top = $RangeToCover.Top
    $ChartObj.Left = $RangeToCover.Left
    $ChartObj.Height = $RangeToCover.Height
    $ChartObj.Width = $RangeToCover.Width
```

However once i did this the Chart Name is changed to be Memory (Wich is the second column) and the reading did not include the CPU (Only the Memory)

Also getting an error related to the ChartTitle as below:

The property 'Text' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:821 char:5
+     $NsxManagerResourcesHistoricChart.ChartTitle.Text = "NSX Manager  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Not sure what is the issue here.

Graph Output after adding the above 2 lines is as follow [graph after editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZLmI.png)

Comment: $xlPlotBy::xlColumns would have only one Sieres of Data Entry and this is why it was ploting only one value.